# How do I read from a csv file using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read data from a csv file in python using pandas, but I keep getting a file not found error message.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#import experimental data
headers = ['wave', 'otti', 'sc', 'trans','wave_sol', 'sol_15am']
df = pd.read_csv('/Documents/Research/expdata.csv', names=headers, 
skiprows=[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that Pandas cannot find the file as that is the error returned by Pandas.

**Linux:**

I see in your path, you have `/Documents/Research/expdata.csv` on a Linux/Unix system your "Documents" folder is likely located in `/home/<<username>>/Documents`.  Linux systems will be case sensitive when it comes to file paths.  So, `/home/zerodf/Documents` is **NOT** equivalent to `/home/zerodf/documents`.

**Mac OS:**

On Mac OS, I believe that would be `/Users/<<username>>/Documents`.  Mac OS is [case insensitive, but preserving](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive).

**Windows:**

On Windows, that will be `C:\users\<<username>>\Documents`.  Windows systems will not be case sensitive.  On Windows, `C:\zerodf\documents` is equivalent to `C:\zerodf\Documents`.

Python is going to take path's very literally.  However, when it comes to interactive data science, [ipython](https://ipython.org/) will help you with path autocompetion.